# Use of Environment variable to access multiple files using sqlcmd scripts

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

Sorry Andriy for creating confusion with my problem statements: Let me be very specific with what i need. Problem Statement 1: I have got few text files having numerous records which are delimited by pipeline. These files are there in a remote windows server which are the source file for our daily load into a sql server table. I want to write a scripts which will get the filename from the source file path and the number of records in it.–

Next task is to get the counts from sql server table which is ther in an another server(remote) and then validate the counts of table and file.

Comment: Word problems... They can be funny sometimes, while still being impenetrable. Anyway, you seem to be facing several very different issues here, and that makes your question too broad to answer. Please focus on solving a specific problem. Iterating through an Excel sheet's column cells? Or using an environment variable to access a file, whatever that may mean? Or putting those things together *provided they have already been solved*? Please be specific enough so as not to make the answerer write an entire book chapter to address all your issues.

Comment: Sorry Andriy for creating confusion with my problem statements: Let me be very specific with what i need. Problem Statement 1: I have got few text files having numerous records which are delimited by pipeline. These files are there in a remote windows server which are the source file for our daily load into a sql server table. I want to write a scripts which will get the filename from the source file path and the number of records in it.– 

Next task is to get the counts from sql server table which is ther in an another server(remote) and then validate the counts of table and file.